# Datagrid in MVC4 to list uploaded files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, webgrid, mvcgrid

I have cshtml page, it has a **browse button** and an **add button**. I can browse a file and while I click the add button I want to show the file name and a delete option on a grid on the same page. Each time while adding the files I want to update the grid with the files added. How this can be done. I am new to MVC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use jQuery multiple file upload plugin.
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/